# Visual C++ Class Library

Tags: c++, class, visual-c++

I'm currently learning C++ (working my way through Accelerated C++ by Koenig & Moo) and I've recently decided to get my head around MS visual C++ in Windows. Previously I did all my programming in Linux using only vim and G++. I want to implement a class, nothing special, just an example class from the book called Vec, and I've never done this in visual C++ before. So, I chose 'New Project' -> 'Class Library' and I'm confronted with this:

```
// Vec.h

#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace Vec {

public ref class Class1
{
    // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
};
}
```

Now, I know the book is not specific to any particular development environment, but practically none of these things are the same as I've seen in there. I've only ever seen classes defined in header files like:

```
#ifndef VEC_H
#define VEC_H

class Vec {
public:
    // things here

private:
    // other things here
};

#endif
```

Is Class library for something else, or is the book I'm reading obsolete? And can anyone give me some idea of what is going on and how the two definitions differ?

Comment: Doesn't look like C++. Could be C++/CLI? Microsoft sticks a ton of non-standard crap on you without being clear about it. They're also using `#pragma` instead of include guards and naughtily writing `using namespace` in a header. You could just delete their template and start again.

Comment: The book isn't obsolete at all. What you are confronted with is not standard C++.

Comment: BTW you are absolutely right about your C++ example and that books are generally agnostic of specific platforms/implementations. Bravo!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Deleting the template code and replacing it won't fix the compiler options, which are set to `/clr` by that template.  Best to start over with a Win32 project.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yep okay. Wrote that w.r.t just the crappiness not the languageness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You chose to make a .NET Class Library.  Visual C++ can compile C++/CLI code that turns into .NET programs and libraries.  It's almost certainly not what you want.

Choose one of the "Win32" project types instead, prob ably "Win32 Console Application", to get a project containing standard C++ code.

If you want a new class, you shouldn't use the "New Project" dialog for that.  The "New File" dialog has options for templates for C++ headers, source files, and other useful stuff.

Comment: I think there's something like an "Empty Project" template (haven't used VS in a while). If so, that's probably best for a beginner just trying things out.

Comment: @Cubic: There's an option when creating a Win32 Console Application to start with an empty project -- you get the build options set correctly for standard C++ code and no source files.  The "Empty Project" template is pretty useless on the other hand -- it won't build anything, you have to provide a makefile.

Comment: @BenVoigt: empty project is pretty much the Win32 Console Application (I haven't diffed the settings though). Add a .cpp file and a `main` and it will build just fine.

Comment: @EdS.: You're talking about "Win32 Project" with the empty option checked.  There's another option for an actually empty project (not in the C++ section), I guess it's called "Blank Solution" (at least in VS2010).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ahh, ok, I gotcha.  You're right, Empty Win32 project.  I guess I've never stumbled up the "completely empty project file" option :D

Answer (score 3):

You chose a C++/CLI template (see: `ref class`) which uses the .NET framework.  It is literally a completely different language.

Personally, I always chose empty project for a DLL or simple exe (I say "simple" because, if I'm making something like an MFC UI, I use their template to add all of the nonsense boilerplate code) and add my files/configuration as needed.